# C application that is executed by PHP does not show output on browser until its execution is completed

Tags: php, html, c, apache

I am executing a C application by a web interface in PHP. The output of the C application is displayed on the browser after its complete execution. I want that as soon as C application "printf" function prints an output it should be displayed on the browser.

I tried to use flush, ob_flush, ob_flush_end, setting header in PHP but it didnt worked.
Then added fflush(stdout) in my C application and it immediately updates the output on the browser.

The problem is that I dont want to add anything in C application I want to achieve this in PHP. My C code and PHP script are gievn below

hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
 int i = 0;

 for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
            printf("hello world\n");
            //fflush(stdout);//it immediately updates the browser output if uncommented
            sleep(1);
    }

}
```

PHP

```
<?php
execute_prog('/var/www/html/test/./hello3');

function execute_prog($exe)
{

    set_time_limit(1800);

    $exe_command = escapeshellcmd($exe);

    $descriptorspec = array(

            0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin -> for execution

            1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout -> for execution

            2 => array("pipe", "w") // stderr 

        );

    $process = proc_open($exe_command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);//creating child process


     if (is_resource($process))
      {
            while(1)
        {
            $write  = NULL; 
            $read   = array($pipes[1]);
            $err    = NULL;
            $except = NULL;

            if (false === ($num_changed_streams = stream_select($read, $write, $except, 0)))
            {
                /* Error handling */
                                echo "Errors\n";
            } 
            else if ($num_changed_streams > 0)
            {
                     /* At least on one of the streams something interesting happened */

                        //echo "Data on ".$num_changed_streams." descriptor\n";

                 if($read)
                 {
                     echo "Data on child process STDOUT\n";

                     $s = fgets($pipes[1]);
                     print $s."</br>";

                     ob_flush();
                     flush();
                 }
                 else if($write)
                 {
                     echo "Data on child process STDIN\n";

                 }
                 else if($err)
                 {
                     echo "Data on child process STDERR\n";

                 }

                $num_changed_streams = 0;
            }


        }

        fclose($pipes[0]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[2]);
        echo "exitcode: ".proc_close($process)."\n";
    }   


return $ret;
}

?>
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `unbuffer` command in front of your program:

```
execute_prog('unbuffer /var/www/html/test/./hello3');
```

It will open a pseudo TTY and the libC will switch to line buffering instead of full buffering.

Detailed info available in man: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html

Comment: For those who like to learn how this is done: http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/pty/unbuffer.c.html

Comment: It requires to install expect-dev  utillity, i did that and its working thankyou :)

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with `stdio` stream buffering. When you run `hello3` on the terminal you only observe immediate results because `stdout` is connected to a terminal and in terminals it is by default line buffered.

The `stdio` library is clever enough to detect that when run on a pipe no terminal is connected to `stdout` and turns it to fully buffered (for performance reasons). This is why adding `fflush(stdout);` updates your browser immediately.

if you want your browser to receive results immediately then either `fflush(stdout);` each time when you want an update or change buffering to line buffered or unbuffered.

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); // no buffering
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0); // line buffered
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 0); // fully buffered
```

**Edit:**

If you badly can't modify the C executable then you can inject a library that will set this option for you. Here is a minimal example:

```
// unbuf.c
#include <stdio.h>

void _nobuff_initialiser(void) {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); // no buffering   
}
```

Compile with

```
cc -o unbuf.so -fPIC -shared -init __nobuff_initialiser unbuf.c      # Linux
cc -o unbuf.dylib -dynamiclib -init __nobuff_initialiser unbuf.c     # OS X
```

Run with environment variables set

```
LD_PRELOAD=<pathto unbuf.so> ./hello3                      # Linux
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=<path to unbuf.dylib> ./hello3       # OS X
```

Or from PHP:

```
putenv("LD_PRELOAD=<pathto unbuf.so>");                    # Linux
putenv("DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=<path to unbuf.dylib>");     # OS X
```

Comment: in other words: unfortunaltely you can't solve the problem in php (+1)

Comment: Well, you could technically `ptrace` your C program and inject a `setvbuf`, or inject a library that executes a `setvbuf`, but that is a lot of overhead!

Comment: @Sergey L you are the man love your solution and will use this technique in my other C programs but right now i adopted the "unbuffer ./hello3" as solution because it was quite handy. Really thank you for your help